# How can I pass images to a CSS Paint Worklet?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, css-houdini, css-paint-api

I am trying to create a custom background for a h1-tag using the CSS Paint API. The background should be clipped to the text, so essentially I would like to 'color' it.

- Unfortunatly '-webkit-canvas' was deprecated. A requirement is to actually use a h1 tag, and not just render text in a canvas and use composition modes.
- I would like to pass in multiple images to draw with ctx.drawImage.

The spec is pretty clear on this:

```js
CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--my-image',
  syntax: '<image> | none',
  initialValue: 'none',
  inherits: false,
});

class MyWorklet {
  static get inputProperties() { 
    return ['--my-image']; 
  }

  paint(ctx, geom, properties) {
    const img = properties.get('--my-image');
    console.log(img);
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10,150,180);    
  }
}
registerPaint('myworklet', MyWorklet);
```

However, Chromium has no support for this. The current workaround seems to be to pass the images through the `background-image: ,` property. This will unfortunatly collide with registering the paint worklet as background-image (`background-image: paint(worklet); background-clip: text;`).

What are other ways to pass images into the paint worklet? Doesn't necessarily have to be through css variables. I am fine with hardcoding or importing images directly into the paint worklet.

Comment: Wait that this API matures enough so it has more support? You probably ate still better just appending an absolutely positionned canvas on that h1, like we did for 10 years.

Comment: How does positioning the canvas on the h1 solve it? In would like to 'background-clip: text' it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You didn't say you wanted to clip that canvas with the h1's text... Why not do that on the canvas itself? You could keep the h1's text transparent on top of it. Otherwise svg could also be a solution here.

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/1yo8jwhf/ but https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416597/3702797 already gave you the correct direction anyway.

Comment: That's great, exactly what I was looking for. I never would've guessed that putting the canvas inside the h1 tag would clip it. I assumed the canvas will render inside the border-box. After trying I will provide and accept answers.