# Approaches for setting an animated canvas as background clipped text of a heading tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, houdini

I would like to clip an animated canvas as background to a `<h1 />`. The requirements are:

- Use an actual `<h1 />` tag instead of rendered heading in canvas.
- Use of images to be rendered with `ctx.drawImage()`.

```css
h1 { 
  color: transparant;
  background-image: <some-canvas>;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

There are several approaches I've tried so far with varying success:

- Creating a regular canvas and setting it as background of the `<h1 />`-tag using `-webkit-canvas` and `-moz-element`. This approach ticked all of my requirements but unfortunatly `-webkit-canvas` was deprecated along with `document.getCSSCanvasContext("2d")` in Chromium. Safari is the only working browser.
- Using the CSS Paint API (Houdini). Using a `requestAnimationFrame()` to update a css var I can keep ticking the animation and do the animation I would like to implement. However, in Chromium, passing in images has to be done using a workaround (instead of creating a property of type image, images have to be passed in using `background-image`, making me unable to use the `background-image` to tell CSS Paint to use my worklet as background. The spec is not entirely implemented.
- Creating an inline svg as background-image:  `url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><foreignObject><canvas id='..'/></foreignObject></svg>");` and trying to update that canvas using `requestAnimationFrame`. Does not work at all.

Are there any other methods I could try?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't *have* to be a `background-image`, you *could* put the `canvas` element inside the `h1` element, match the `canvas` `width` and `height` to that of the `h1` element, give it a lower `z-index` than the text in the `h1` element so that it appears to be behind the text, acting like a background.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/*
  Set the dimensions of the canvas to 
  match the parent h1 element
----------------------------------------------------------*/
setCanvasSize();

// (and for demonstrative purposes, scale on window resize)
window.addEventListener('resize', setCanvasSize, false);

function setCanvasSize () {
  var _w = canvas.parentNode.clientWidth;
  var _h = canvas.parentNode.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = _w;
  canvas.height = _h;
  canvas.style.width = "'" + _w + "px'";
  canvas.style.height = "'" + _h + "px'";
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------
  All this code below is just a ball animation borrowed from MDN
  to illustrate what I'm suggesting.
  
  Source: MDN 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Advanced_animations 
*/
var raf;
var running = false;

var ball = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  vx: 5,
  vy: 1,
  radius: 50,
  color: 'blue',
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
};

function clear() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  ball.draw();
  ball.x += ball.vx;
  ball.y += ball.vy;

  if (ball.y + ball.vy > canvas.height || ball.y + ball.vy < 0) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
  }
  if (ball.x + ball.vx > canvas.width || ball.x + ball.vx < 0) {
    ball.vx = -ball.vx;
  }

  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
   
if (!running) {
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  running = true;
}

ball.draw();
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```css
h1 {
  /* Important for positioning the span element */
  position: relative;
  
  /* Cosmetic/demonstrative */
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 span { 
  /* Vertically and horizontally center the text */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
  /*
    Text will appear above canvas as long as its 
    z-index > canvas' z-index
  */
  z-index: 2;

}

h1 canvas {
  /* this will make the canvas appear behind the text */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; 
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum etc.</span>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</h1>
```

Just a thought anyway, maybe you can try it out and expand on the idea to suit your needs. I'm not 100% sure what you're working on so apologies if it's not helpful.

Comment: You'd have a better result placing your canvas absolutely, so that it doesn't affect the size of the h1. Also, better use a ResizeObserver (on the parent) to set the size of your canvas.